# how to draw different paths between locations in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a code which is used to draw a line between two points on a google map, but I do not know how to draw multiple possible paths between two location. Is there any way to draw different paths between two locations?

thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: try this https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points